# Update clock on virtualbox virtual machine with cent os from host

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox, date, clock-synchronization

I have a virtual machine, with cent os installed, and everytime I sleep the host computer, the clock of the VM goes out of sync. I would like it to pick up the current time from virtualbox - which I would expect it to do naturally.

How can I force the clock to update from the host machine - or better still, have it stay in sync automatically?

Comment: It should sync after a few minutes. If not, why not installing a NTP server on the host? Btw, Are you running Guest Additions?

Comment: I can not get network access to update from NTP server. I am not sure if guest additions is running. I am fairly sure it was installed. The VM has been provided to me at my job.

Comment: I did a small research and everything I found tells that either Guest additions or Virtual Box itself syncs the time without intervention. You may got it disabled. The following command may enable it (Use on host): `vboxmanage setextradata <vmname> “VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled” “0″`

Comment: you're welcome. Happy hacking!